# Is there a way to tell what the default authentication is using the partners.desire2learn.com page

Tags: desire2learn

I am looking for the steps that I can verify what the authentication type is for partners.desire2learn.com site?

Answer (score 0):

There are no apis or mechanisms to verify authentication type. If you just need to know what is going on for a single site, sometimes you can infer from the urls that are visited during a login sequence; but for example ldap login in D2L is not distinguishable from an internal account.

If you are having login problems I would open a support ticket or contact the partner group.